# Dictionary and WAV file playback issue in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dictionary, wav

each button has a  wav file which plays when a button is pressed

```
Private Sub soundButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles soundButton.Click

    Dim btn As Button

    For Each btn In panel1.Controls    
        Dim snd As New System.Media.SoundPlayer(multiple_wav_files)
        snd.Play()
    Next 
End Sub
```

How do I go about getting the wav file to play and complete before playing another wav file ?

```
Dim snd As New System.Media.SoundPlayer(multiple_wav_files)
```

What happens here is that it jumps straight to the last button and plays its sound.

Comment: right after the for loop is created at `For Each btn In panel1.Controls` if i add a msgbox  it will  show the message box for each button but for the sound it , will only play the last buttons sound .

i just want to know how i can wait for a wav to complete here `Dim snd As New System.Media.SoundPlayer(multiple_wav_files)` before moving to the next wav file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [SoundPlayer.Play Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.play.aspx) explicitly says that it "plays the sound using a new thread". Use [My.Computer.Audio.Play](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cf1shcah%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Method instead, specifying `AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete`.

Comment: thanks 
i got it fixed 
`My.Computer.Audio.Play((ttsdic.Item(key)), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)`

but the distance between playback is too great

Comment: What do you mean by distance?